# Какую использовать библиотеку для работы с mysql на pytho3?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Посоветуйте пожалуйста какие-то библиотеки на 3-й питон для работы с MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.[Первая](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3)

2.[Вторая](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

3.[Третяя](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/)

Сам лично пользуюсь второй